# Insert Function : GenerateTransaction()

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, function

Im creating a pageant scoring system.

This is my database:

[image]

My question is, how can I make a function that when executed, it will add a record in Transaction table but leaves the Score blank or 0 based on the count of Contestant.

This is the function I have but closes immediately and does nothing on transaction table.

```
Private Sub GenerateTransaction()
    ' load event of the logged in judge
    JudgeTableAdapter.FillByJudge(Me.PSSdbDataSet.Judge, JudgeID)
    JudgeBindingSource.DataSource = PSSdbDataSet.Judge

    For Each drEventJudges As DataRow In Me.PSSdbDataSet.Judge.Rows
        ' load participants by event
        ContestantTableAdapter.FillByContest(Me.PSSdbDataSet.Contestant, drEventJudges("Cont_id"))


        CategoryTableAdapter.FillByContest(Me.PSSdbDataSet.Category, drEventJudges("Cont_id"))
        ' MessageBox.Show(Me.PSSdbDataSet.Category.Rows.Count.ToString, "Category Count")
        For Each drCategory As DataRow In Me.PSSdbDataSet.Category.Rows
            CriteriaTableAdapter.FillByCategory(Me.PSSdbDataSet.Criteria, drCategory("Cat_id"))
            ' MessageBox.Show(Me.PSSdbDataSet.Criteria.Rows.Count.ToString, "Criteria Count")
            For Each drParticipant As DataRow In Me.PSSdbDataSet.Contestant.Rows
                ' MessageBox.Show(Me.PSSdbDataSet.Contestant.Rows.Count.ToString, "Participants Count")
                For Each drCriteria As DataRow In Me.PSSdbDataSet.Criteria.Rows
                    TransactionTableAdapter.Insert(drEventJudges("Judge_id"), _
                                                    drParticipant("Cont_id"), _
                                                    drCriteria("Cri_id"), _
                                                    0)
                Next
            Next
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The likely issue is that you have an exception that is occurring, since Transaction is often a reserved word in databases.

If this is not the case, then I would recommend adding a default value (constraint) to the Score so that when a new record is created, it is always initialized to the default value.

In SQL Server, this would look (roughly) like:

```
ALTER TABLE [Transaction]
  ALTER COLUMN
    score       int         NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
```